# GData Objective-C Client Contact Service

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, gmail, gdata

I downloaded the last GData client via SVN https://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/
I succesfully compiled it and I integrated successfully the static library inside my project.

I need to retrieve all gmail contacts about a google username:

```
- (GDataServiceGoogleContact *)contactService {

    static GDataServiceGoogleContact* service = nil;

    if (!service) {
        service = [[GDataServiceGoogleContact alloc] init];

        [service setShouldCacheResponseData:YES];
        [service setServiceShouldFollowNextLinks:YES];
    }

    // update the username/password each time the service is requested
    NSString *username = usr.text;
    NSString *password = psw.text;

    [service setUserCredentialsWithUsername:username
                                   password:password];

    return service;
}

- (IBAction)getContacts:(id)sender; {
    GDataServiceGoogleContact *gc =[self contactService];
    NSURL *feedURL = [GDataServiceGoogleContact contactFeedURLForUserID:usr.text];

    GDataServiceTicket *ticket;
    ticket = [gc fetchFeedWithURL:feedURL
                         delegate:self
                didFinishSelector:@selector(ticket:finishedWithFeed:error:)];
    [self startLoading];
}
```

The callback selector looks like this:

```
- (void)ticket:(GDataServiceTicket *)ticket finishedWithFeed:(GDataFeedContact *)feed
         error:(NSError *)error {
    [self stopLoading];
    if (error == nil) {
        NSArray *entries = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[feed entries]];

        if ([entries count] > 0) {
            for (GDataEntryContact *firstContact in entries) {

                NSString *name  = [((GDataNameElement*)[[firstContact name] fullName]) stringValue];

                NSString *email = ([firstContact emailAddresses] != nil && [[firstContact emailAddresses] count]!=0) ? [[[firstContact emailAddresses] objectAtIndex:0] stringValueForAttribute:@"address"]: NSLocalizedString(@"not found",@"");
                if (name == nil) {
                    name = email;
                }

                BBGmailContact *tmpContact = [[BBGmailContact alloc] initWithName:name email:email];
                [contacts addObject:tmpContact];
                [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

            }
        [gmailDelegate contactsDidDownload:contacts];

        } else {
            [self createAlertView:NSLocalizedString(@"Warning", @"") message:NSLocalizedString(@"No contact found", @"")];
        }
    } else {
        [self createAlertView:NSLocalizedString(@"Error", @"Error") message:NSLocalizedString(@"Please, check your user and password", @"")];

    }
}
```

Why is every entry of entries a kind of class: GDataEntryBase instead GDataEntryContact?
Where is my error? Can someone help me?

Comment: If the project GData is present in the workspace this code works fine, but if you link only the compiled static library and the Headers this code doesn't work.

Comment: if you get the solution i am also try fetching gmail contact but not get success. if you done please give a solution or atleast a way. how should i go ahed.

Answer (score -1):

Entries are created as GDataEntryBase if the application does not have the service-specific classes for Contacts compiled and linked into the app.

Be sure too that the appropriate build flags for the Contacts service are specified as described [in the docs](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/wiki/BuildingTheLibrary#Removing_Unneeded_Code).

Comment: The build flag was setted good. Where Can I find the appropriate documents how to create and set the specific class for the service?

Comment: - (GDataServiceGoogleContact *)contactService {
    
    static GDataServiceGoogleContact* service = nil;
    
    if (!service) {
        service = [[GDataServiceGoogleContact alloc] init];
        
        [service setShouldCacheResponseData:YES];
        [service setServiceShouldFollowNextLinks:YES];
    }
    
    // update the username/password each time the service is requested
    NSString *username = usr.text;
    NSString *password = psw.text;
    
    [service setUserCredentialsWithUsername:username
                                   password:password];
    
    return service;
}